# Mongodb is grouping sorts by date

Tags: mongodb, sorting, date, meteor

I've created a collection in Mongodb that stores articles each with a field called "likes" that stores the number of likes.

On my webpage I want to sort the articles by the number of likes from greatest to least reading from the whole db. Which works but it sorting in a given time group.

Example:
So it sorts by number of likes (day 1) then by number of likes (day 2) etc. How do I fix this?

```
Template.sectionBodyAll.helpers({
    articles: function(){
      return Articles.find({},{sort: {like: -1}});
});
```

Articles is the name of the collection and sectionBodyAll is the name of the page/template

The sorting looks like this on the page:

- Article #1 - 3 likes - Aug 11
- Article #2 - 3 likes - Aug 11
- Article #4 - 4 likes - Aug 13
- Article #3 - 2 likes - Aug 13
- Article #5 - 1 likes - Aug 14

It should look like

- Article #4 - 4 likes - Aug 13
- Article #1 - 3 likes - Aug 11
- Article #2 - 3 likes - Aug 11
- Article #3 - 2 likes - Aug 13
- Article #5 - 1 likes - Aug 14

Comment: Please show an example document and the helper code you are using to show them.

Comment: ... again I still don't see an example document. What is the date? `createdAt`, `likeDate`... we can't write a query if we don't have the schema.

Comment: in Article insert it is createdAt: new Date()

Comment: Fixed it was a syntactical error on my part.

Comment: [Works fine here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/E6dZS8XWXrEm3nRjH/SortByLikes)